# More informative flair

Tags: feature-request, flair, feed

It would be nice if Stack Overflow had a more informative flair I could place on my personal website. I'd like to place an entire feed of my activity on my personal website.

Comment: Hmmm.  You'd probably need to use [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Answer (score 9):

You can consume your [user RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1235950) to get all your activity.